# RxJava экзепшен CalledFromWrongThreadException при subscribe

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Имею вот такой код: 
**io.reactivex**

```
 get().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .doOnSubscribe(d-> getViewState().showLoadingView(d))
                .doFinally(() -> getViewState().hideLoadingView())
                .subscribe(data->{
                    getViewState().showData(data);
                }, er->{
                    Log.e("TutorialPresenter", er.toString());
                });
```

И почему то в subscribe получаю экзепшен `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Но я ведь делаю `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` что не так?

Comment: так может у вас не mainThread создал этот View?

Comment: Задал вопрос и нашел ответ. Оказывается виноват .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Comment: оставьте его как ответ, чтобы другие, если встретят такую ошибку, поняли как решить :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В моем случае

```
get()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                //переход в поток вычислений
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // переход в UI поток
.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)                // переход в поток вычислений (вот из-за этого и экзепшен)
```

Правильный вариант при задержке

```
get()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                //переход в поток вычислений
.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)                // переход в поток вычислений
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // переход в UI поток
```

либо

```
get()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                //переход в поток вычислений    
.delay (5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // переход в UI поток
```